# Listbox 2 columns from openfiledialog path and filename to database

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listbox which i can fill trough openfiledialog, which works but not the way i want it. I need 2 columns in my listbox 1 for the filepath and 1 for the fileName next to each other.

also i have another button which inserts all fileNames into the database, which works also but i also need the second column to update the path column in my database

Ive tried to make 2 columns 1 for the filename and 1 for the filepath, unfortunately i could only make 1 column work for my filename.

```
This is the code for filling in the listbox 

private void btnOpenFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        lbfiles.Items.Clear();
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames)

                lbfiles.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename));
        }
    }
```

this is the code for inserting into the database

```
  private void BtnToDatabase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool dupe = false;
        foreach (String  string2 in lbfiles.Items.Cast<String>().ToList())
        {
            {
                string cat1 = string2.Substring(0, string2.Length);

                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    String query = "INSERT INTO tblBestanden2 (BestandNaam,toegewezen,Username,Status) VALUES (@BestandNaam, @toegewezen, @username, @Status)";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BestandNaam", cat1);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toegewezen", "1");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "0");

                        sqlCon.Open();
                        int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        if (!dupe)
                        {
                            if (result == 0)
                            {
                                sqlCon.Close();
                                MessageBox.Show("error");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sqlCon.Close();
                                MessageBox.Show("toegevoegd");
                            }
                            dupe = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If there is any confusion about my question please tell me and i will try my best to elaborate

Comment: I`d suggest creating a simple ViewModel for the items. In that case a class with two properties and bind each of them to a column from xaml. Then you can use these objects to get the values for the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class with two properties:

```
public class File
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

And instances of this one to the `ListBox`:

```
private void btnOpenFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lbfiles.Items.Clear();
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames)
            lbfiles.Items.Add(new File() { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename), Path = filename });
    }
}
```

You would then get the values by casting the items to `File` objects in your `BtnToDatabase_Click` event handler:

```
private void BtnToDatabase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool dupe = false;
    foreach (File file in lbfiles.Items.OfType<File>())
    {
        string name = file.Name;
        string path = file.Path;
                ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In foreach statement, filepath is not included when this condition `openFileDialog.ShowDialog()` gets true, you are getting only filename. To get filepath, use `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileName);`, you could get filepath for the filename